# How to Raise Event Item Clicked of a ListView that exists inside another ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm creating a Prism Xamarin Form app, in my page I have nested listviews (4 levels), the problem is that I'm not able to raise event when I tap on an item inside second, third and fourth level listviews, the event is working only for the top level listview, knowing that the 4 listviews have the same item source type.

I searched a lot concerning how to raise event when I tap item of a list view that exists inside another parent list view and I got not answer that fit my case, I tried to method:

1-

> ItemSelected = {Binding SelectedItem}

2-

> EventToCommandBehavior 
>         EventName="ItemTapped" 
>         Command="{Binding SelectCustomEntityCommand}"
>         EventArgsConverter="{converters:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter}"

The following are the code structures:

1- CustomEntity Class

> ```
> public class CustomEntity 
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public bool Expanded { get; set; }
>     public List<CustomEntity> LevelTwo { get; set; }
>     public List<CustomEntity> LevelThree { get; set; }
>     public List<CustomEntity> LevelFour { get; set; }
> }
> ```

2- testNestedListViewsViewModel Class

> ```
> public class testNestedListViewsViewModel : ViewModelBase
> {
>     public testNestedListViewsViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
>         : base(navigationService)
>     {
>         Title = "Test Nested Listviews";
>         LevelOne = new ObservableCollection<CustomEntity>();
>     }
>
>
>     private ObservableCollection<CustomEntity> _LevelOne;
>     public ObservableCollection<CustomEntity> LevelOne
>     {
>         get { return _LevelOne; }
>         set { SetProperty(ref _LevelOne, value); }
>     }
>
>     private DelegateCommand<CustomEntity> _selectCustomEntity;
>     public DelegateCommand<CustomEntity> SelectCustomEntityCommand => _selectCustomEntity ?? (_selectCustomEntity = new DelegateCommand<CustomEntity>(ShowCustomEntityDetails));
>
>     private void ShowCustomEntityDetails(CustomEntity paramData)
>     {
>         var x = paramData;
>     }
>
>
>
>     public override void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
>     {
>         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>         {
>             LevelOne.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = i + 1, Name = "Name " + (i + 1), Expanded = false });
>         }
>         foreach (var item in LevelOne)
>         {
>             item.LevelTwo = new List<CustomEntity>();
>             item.LevelTwo.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 100, Name = "K", Expanded = false });
>             item.LevelTwo.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 101, Name = "1", Expanded = false });
>             item.LevelTwo.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 102, Name = "2", Expanded = false });
>             item.LevelTwo.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 103, Name = "3", Expanded = false });
>             item.LevelTwo.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 104, Name = "4", Expanded = false });
>             item.LevelTwo.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 105, Name = "5", Expanded = false });
>             foreach (var item2 in item.LevelTwo)
>             {
>                 item2.LevelThree = new List<CustomEntity>();
>                 item2.LevelThree.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 200, Name = "BOK 1", Expanded = false });
>                 item2.LevelThree.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 201, Name = "BOK 2", Expanded = false });
>                 item2.LevelThree.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 202, Name = "BOK 3", Expanded = false });
>                 item2.LevelThree.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 203, Name = "BOK 4", Expanded = false });
>                 item2.LevelThree.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 204, Name = "BOK 5", Expanded = false });
>                 item2.LevelThree.Add(new CustomEntity() { Id = 205, Name = "BOK 6", Expanded = false });
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
> }
> ```

3- Xaml file

> ```
>       <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
>
>       <ListView Grid.Row="1"
>                 BackgroundColor="White"
>                 SeparatorColor="Gray"
>                 ItemsSource="{Binding LevelOne}"
>                 VerticalOptions="Fill">
>           <ListView.Behaviors>
>               <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" 
>                                         Command="{Binding SelectCustomEntityCommand}"
>                                         EventArgsConverter="{converters:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter}" />
>           </ListView.Behaviors>
>           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
>               <DataTemplate>
>                   <ViewCell>
>                       <Grid>
>                           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
>                               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
>                           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                           <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Blue"></Label>
>                           <ListView Grid.Row="1"
>                                 BackgroundColor="White"
>                                 SeparatorColor="Gray"
>                                 ItemsSource="{Binding LevelTwo}"
>                                 VerticalOptions="Fill">       
>                               <ListView.Behaviors>
>                                   <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" 
>                                         Command="{Binding SelectCustomEntityCommand}"
>                                         EventArgsConverter="{converters:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter}" />
>                               </ListView.Behaviors>
>                               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
>                                   <DataTemplate>
>                                       <ViewCell>
>                                           <Grid>
>                                               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                                                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
>                                                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
>                                               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                                               <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Red"></Label>
>
>                                           </Grid>
>                                       </ViewCell>
>                                   </DataTemplate>
>                               </ListView.ItemTemplate>
>                           </ListView>
>                       </Grid>
>                   </ViewCell>
>               </DataTemplate>
>           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
> ```

I expected when I tap on an item in the second listview to raise the event named: "SelectCustomEntityCommand"
But I noticed that only first level listview raise that event.

Comment: Nesting listviews is not a good practice, to begin with, and hence you are facing these issues and discrepancies

Comment: @G.hakim I appreciate your comment, but I really believe that everything can be done in programming, but since I have little experience in XAML work so I'm slow to do some progress on this.

Comment: Actually, not everything can be done in programming anyway you might wanna read this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100280/nested-listview-in-xamarin-forms-listview-inside-another-listview

Comment: Ok @G.hakim thanks a lot, do you think is possible to call a method in the CustomEntity class that envoke an event on testNestedListViewsViewModel? I mean some kind of method reference or something, I don't know if that is possible

Comment: You can check out messaging center for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: why do you even need a 4 level nested ListViews? i think this might be a XY problem, hence the reasson you are encountering this issues, can you explain why you need a ListView inside a ListView inside (...)??

Comment: @G.hakim I read the link you provided, unfortunately, this does not support MVVM Prism Framework, I actually need something like that, I need to subscribe a message and then to fire it with some arguments when I put a method inside CustomEntity class it fired when I tap on the second level listview but I need then to have an event in the main page to be fired.

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais I have a client specs that needs to browse some Standards in the following hierarchical: Subject > Grade Level > Domain > Topic, so that the user can browse for standards using that tree of listviews

Comment: Have you tried RepeaterView? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CustomControls.RepeaterView/; like the Name Says, it repeates views, so you can use a ScrollView with a RepeaterView inside RepeaterView inside (...), with will give you what you want

Comment: but here is an warning: this method doesn't use the ListView Recycling method, your list views have images? if they have or you have alot of items binded, it might not be a good solution

Comment: Thanks @RicardoDiasMorais I will give it a try